# Фулл-скрин верстка на swiper.js. Когда включается freeMode и вёрстка становится обычной, остаются отступы снизу. Как их убрать?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper

Остается отступ снизу, причем бывает разной длинны, когда вхожу в режим разработчика этот отступ пропадает, будто блоки ужимаются под контент, а длинна страницы остается прежней, но учитывая что отступ не всегда одной длинны понятия не имею что происходит. Возможно ли такое, что железо не справляется, потому что в целом сайт иногда подвисает? Делаю на OpenServer, но когда делал на Gulp такая же штука была.

скрипт:

```
    let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
let pageSlider = new Swiper('.page', {
    wrapperClass: "page__wrapper",
    slideClass: "page__screen",
    simulateTouch: false,
    direction: 'vertical',
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    parallax: true,
    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
        onlyInViewport: true,
        pageUpDown: true,
    },
    mousewheel: {
        sensitivity: 1,
    },
    speed: 800,
    abserver: true,
    abserverParents: true,
    abserverSliderChildren: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.page__pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
        clickable: true,
        bulletClass: "page__bullet",
        bulletActiveClass: "page__bullet_active",
    },
    scrollbar: {
        el: ".page__scroll",
        dragClass: "page__drag-scroll",
        draggable: true
    },
    init: false,
    on: {
        init: function () {
            setScrollType();
            wrapper.classList.add('loaded');
        },
        slideChange: function () {
        },
        resize: function () {
            setScrollType();
        },
    },
});
function setScrollType() {
    if (wrapper.classList.contains('free')) {
        wrapper.classList.remove('free');
        pageSlider.params.freeMode = false;
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < pageSlider.slides.length; index++) {
        const pageSlide = pageSlider.slides[index];
        const pageSlideContent = pageSlide.querySelector('.screen__content');
        if (pageSlideContent) {
            const pageSlideContentHeight = pageSlideContent.offsetHeight;
            if (pageSlideContentHeight > window.innerHeight) {
                pageSlider.params.freeMode = true;
                wrapper.classList.add('free');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        pageSlider.params.freeMode = true;
        pageSlider.params.parallax = false;
        wrapper.classList.add('free');
    }
}
pageSlider.init();
```

Стили -

```
.wrapper.free .page__screen {
flex: 0 1 100%;
}
.wrapper.free {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.page {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
  .page__screen {
flex: 1 0 100vh;
position: relative;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

структура-

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <main class="page">
        <div class="page__wrapper">
            <div class="page__screen preview">...</div>
            <div class="page__screen contacts">...</div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

[image: Как выглядит]

Comment: "когда вхожу в режим разработчика этот отступ пропадает" Открыть в отдельном окне пробовали?

Comment: Попробовал, отступ пропадает за счет, изменения размеров окна. Когда в отдельном окне перезагружаешь, отступ снова появляется.

Answer (score 0):

без демки сложно сказать.
Я предположу, что где-то свайпер инлайнит высоту и не убирает ее когда верстка становится обычной. Нужно сделать цикл в js и почистить все элементы от стилей или вызывать ресайз свайпера, если возможно.

Также предположу, что когда входишь в режим разработчика, меняется размер страницы, поэтому, у свайпера срабатывает ресайз и он пересчитывает свои заинлайненные стили, убирая тот отступ